# When using JDBC connector and trying to insert into SQL database, nothing is added when I check the database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, bluej

```
public sqlconnection()
{        
    try
    {
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userlogin","jeddy","admin");
        insertIntoDB();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}    

public void insertIntoDB() throws SQLException
{
    try
    {
        String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

        Class.forName(driver);
        String inpUsername=console.readLine("Enter username: ");    
        String inpPassword=console.readLine("Enter password: ");

        String sql = ("insert into user(username, password) values('"+inpUsername+"', '"+inpPassword+"')");
        PreparedStatement pStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pStmt.executeUpdate();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The console readLine method simply stores the input from the user into variable. I am trying to insert these variable (inpUsername, inpPassword) into my SQL database. After running the code and entering the inputs, I go into MySql command line client and type select * from user and it returns Empty set(0.00 sec)

Comment: (1) Learn to use parameters for queries.  (2) Never pass unencrypted passwords around.

Comment: You may need to commit the transaction and then close the resources.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Your inserting values, but if you didn't commit the transaction means, values will not saved into table.  Add these two lines above the sql statement `dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);` `String sql = ("insert into user(username, password) values('"+inpUsername+"', '"+inpPassword+"')");
        PreparedStatement pStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pStmt.executeUpdate();` `dbConnection.commit();`

Comment: I added those lines replacing dbConnection with myConn and I still have the same problem

Comment: @Arvind Katte, by default each new connection is in auto-commit mode, see [Connection#autoCommit manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit(boolean)) If autocommit is true, then you don't need to commit the transaction.